# Finding the number of cases in which one get 10 head and 2 tails?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In 512 set of 12 tosses of a coin, in how many of cases can one get 10 head and 2 tails?
I cant understand the question.  I understand something that there are 512 coins where every coin can be tossed 12 times.
Am I correct?
If this happen please help me how to proceed.

Comment: You can get it 512 times, if you're lucky. However, the probability of hitting 10 times head in 12 coin tosses, equals ${12 \choose 10} (\frac{1}{2})^{10} (\frac{1}{2})^2$. The expected number of times to hit 10 heads in 512 sets is $\frac{66 \times 2^9}{2^{12}} = 8.25$.

Comment: ya sir I have also done this, but there is no option 8.25

Comment: There are four optionss a)8 b)7 c)7 or 8 d)296  @jvdhooft